# How to add per-file custom header to multipart upload with requests?

Tags: python, http, http-post, python-requests, multipart

python-requests appears to support custom collections as a list/mapping of files to upload.

This in turn should allow me to add custom header fields with each file being uploading within one multipart upload.

How can I actually do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> python-requests appears to support custom collections as a list/mapping of files to upload.
>
> This in turn should allow me to add custom header fields with each file being uploading within one multipart upload.

Nope. Each file in the list/mapping must be a file object (or contents string), a 2-tuple of  a filename and file object (or contents), or a 3-tuple of a filename, file object (or contents) and file type. Anything else is illegal.

Unless [#1640](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/pull/1640) gets accepted upstream, in which case all you'll have to do is use a 4-tuple of a filename, file object (or contents), file type, and header dictionary.

---

The right thing to do at this point is probably to use a different library. For example, if you use `urllib3` directly instead of through the `request` wrappers, it makes what you want to do reasonably easy. You just have to deal with all the extra verbosity of using `urllib3` instead of `requests`.

And meanwhile, you can file a feature request against `requests` and an easier way may get added in the future.

---

But it's a bit frustrating that the functionality you need is all there under the covers, you just can't get to it.

It looks like doing things cleanly would be a nightmare. But it's all pretty simple code, and we can hack our way down to it pretty easily, so let's do that.

Take a look at [`requests.PreparedRequest.prepare_body`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/models.py#L377). It expects each file in `files` to be a tuple of filename, contents or file object, and optionally content-type. It basically just reads in any file objects to convert them to contents, and passes everything straight through to `urllib3.filepost.encode_multipart_formdata`. So, unless we want to replace this code, we're going to need to smuggle the headers in with one of these values. Let's do that by passing `(filename, contents, (content_type, headers_dict))`. So, `requests` itself is unchanged.

What about that [`urllib3.filepost.encode_multipart_formdata`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py#L66) that it calls? As you can see, if you pass it tuples for the files, it calls a function called [`iter_field_objects`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py#L27), which ultimately calls [`urllib3.fields.RequestField.from_tuples`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/fields.py#L55) on each one. But if you look at the `from_tuples` alternate constructor, it says it's there to handle an "old-style" way of constructing RequestField objects, and the normal constructor is there for a "new-style" way, which actually does let you pass in headers.

So, all we need to do is monkeypatch `iter_field_objects`, replacing its last line with one that uses the new-style way, and we should be done. Let's try:

```
import requests
import requests.packages.urllib3
from requests.packages.urllib3.fields import RequestField, guess_content_type
import six

old_iter_field_objects = requests.packages.urllib3.filepost.iter_field_objects
def iter_field_objects(fields):
    if isinstance(fields, dict):
        i = six.iteritems(fields)
    else:
        i = iter(fields)

    for field in i:
      if isinstance(field, RequestField):
        yield field
      else:
        name, value = field
        filename = value[0]
        data = value[1]
        content_type = value[2] if len(value)>2 else guess_content_type(filename)
        headers = None
        if isinstance(content_type, (tuple, list)):
            content_type, headers = content_type
        rf = RequestField(name, data, filename, headers)
        rf.make_multipart(content_type=content_type)
        yield rf
requests.packages.urllib3.filepost.iter_field_objects = iter_field_objects
```

And now:

```
>>> files = {'file': ('foo.txt', 'foo\ncontents\n'), 
...          'file2': ('bar.txt', 'bar contents', 'text/plain'),
...          'file3': ('baz.txt', 'baz contents', ('text/plain', {'header': 'value'}))}
>>. r = request.Request('POST', 'http://example.com', files=files)
>>> print r.prepare().body
--1ee28922d26146e7a2ee201e5bf22c44
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file3"; filename="baz.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain
header: value

baz contents
--1ee28922d26146e7a2ee201e5bf22c44
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file2"; filename="bar.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

bar contents
--1ee28922d26146e7a2ee201e5bf22c44
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

foo
```

Tada!

Note that you need relatively up-to-date `requests`/`urllib3` for this to work. I think `requests` 2.0.0 is sufficient.

Comment: Awesome! I can stick to this for now and petition upstream to implement a tuple-extension, hopefully next version support this :)

Comment: @qarma: If you're going to [add a feature request](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/new), please do so soon and post the link here. Because I might write a patch myself, and I don't want to create a pull request that duplicates your feature request but isn't connected to it.

Comment: @qarma: The patch was even easier than I expected. If you know what you're doing with the command line, you should be able to `pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/abarnert/requests`, test it out, then uninstall and reinstall to get back to the mainline version.